# AJAX code insert not firing *sometimes*

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm trying to modify an ajax callback without actually having access to the original code (don't ask...), and I had found a similar version of the below code on Stack Overflow, which I thought worked great! I put it onto my site, tested it in all browsers, even tested on mobile with success.

So I deployed it this week and, lo and behold, I discovered that for somewhere between a quarter and a third of users this isn't firing correctly. I've been trying like hell to replicate the problem, but again, all of my testing has been successful.

My analytics have told me that the problem is existing for IE, Firefox, and Chrome, and the most up-to-date versions of each, with no tendency toward one browser or another. And from the nature of the problem, I know that the original ajax callback is functioning correctly; it's just my new extra code that's broken.

The site specific code I've written shouldn't be posted online, and stackoverflow isn't jsLint, so I've just replaced it with "some code" here. Suffice to say, I've pored over it looking for potential errors, but I was wondering if anyone knew of any reason why the below code would not work *in some* but not all cases. Because the below is the only code I'm not sure about.

```
function init(){
  "use strict";
  var send = window.XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send,
      onReadyStateChange;

  function sendReplacement(data) {
    if(this.onreadystatechange) {
        this._onreadystatechange = this.onreadystatechange;
    }
    this.onreadystatechange = onReadyStateChangeReplacement;

    return send.apply(this, arguments);
  }

  function onReadyStateChangeReplacement() {

    if(this._onreadystatechange) {
      var end = this._onreadystatechange.apply(this, arguments);
    }

    some code

    if (this._onreadystatechange){return end}
  }

window.XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send = sendReplacement;

}
```

Comment: Well, it wouldn't work for JSONP requests, requests that might save a copy of these methods before you override them, requests made from different frames or different windows, requests made from workers etc. Overall it generally _should_ work though.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look Ben! Looks like the problem actually came from unexpected user behavior. Hope I didn't waste too much of your time.